# Wipe UEFI hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, uefi, wipe

I would like to completely wipe my hard drive but I can't achieve it because it's an UEFI hard drive so :
 - DBAN won't work;
 - I can't use tools such as HDDErase because I can't boot from FreeDOS USB (from what I read it's only a solution for BIOS hard drive).

Moreover I don't have any OS on this computer and when I try to install Ubuntu 18.1 (inside and outside the live version) everything works well until the installer crashes and displays SQUASHS errors.

The only solution I found is to use Blancco Drive Eraser because it seems to work on UEFI hard drives but it seems to be only for professional purposes.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What you are looking to do is unclear.  There is no such thing as a "UEFI HDD", I think you mean GPT, but I am not entirely sure.  Why don't you delete the existing partitions, make it MBR, then use the software you want to use?  You should edit your question to make it clear what you are trying to achieve.  I feel it is important to point out that *UEFI HDDs* do not exist, you either have GPT or MBR

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I have a GPT partition system. How would you do to delete the existing partitions ?

Comment: DVAN doesn’t care what’s on the drive or what format it is in. What you need to do is change your BIOs settings to legacy mode so you can boot and use the DBAN disk, then change it back to UEFI if you want to install an OS.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Legacy boot option in my BIOS settings but only UEFI.

Comment: @Chams Boot into any OS installation environment and delete the partitions, but if your machine doesn’t support legacy mode, you can’t use DBAN so use some other tool which supports UEFI mode

Comment: Thank you. Actually I'm looking for another tool since two days without success. Do you guys have any idea of another tool that would work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DBAN with a UEFI boot system. If you are able to turn off UEFI boot and change it to legacy or CSM in the BIOS/Firmware options. After the HDD will no longer boot and you can boot from DBAN to begin wipe of HDD(s).

Answer (score 0):

Since DBAN has been commercialized by Blancco, its core program `dwipe` [has been forked as `nwipe`](https://github.com/martijnvanbrummelen/nwipe).

And now based on `nwipe`, there is a UEFI/legacy bootable free "successor" of DBAN, [known as ShredOS.](https://github.com/PartialVolume/shredos.x86_64)